# What does "an old-timers' day mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Pulp Fiction (1994)*, Wallace says to Butch:

> Wallace: How many fights you think you got in you anyway? Two? Boxers
> don't have an **old-timers' day**. You came close, but you never made it.
> And if you were gonna make it, you would have made it before now.

What does "an old-timers' day mean?

Old Timer represents someone who has competed in a sport a while ago. Such as Michael Jordan (Famous Basketball Player) would be considered an Old Timer because he competed a long time ago. Old Timers Day I don’t know the meaning of though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right meaning for "old-timer" So an "old-timer's day" is a day for old-timers.

In some sports (eg tennis) a club will run a tournament for old timers:

> Monday is "old-timers day"!  There will be mens and womems trophies in the 40-49, the 50-59 and the 60+ veterans categories. All senior club members are encouraged to enter.

In some sports the veterans games are popular. Tennis is a good example. (Lacking the power of youth, the old-timers have to depend more on skill and finesse.)

You might also have veteran professional sportspeople doing charity matches, for example.

But boxing tends not to have such events.